# AWK to match strings beginning with a number

Tags: regex, bash, unix, awk

I want to print all the lines of a file where the first element of each line begins with a number using `awk`. Below are the details on the data contained in the file and command used:

filename contents:

```
12.44.4444goad ABCDEF/END   
LMNOP/START joker   
98.0 kites
```

command used:

```
awk '{ $1 ~ /^\d[a-zA-Z0-9]*/ }' filename
```

After running the above command, no results are displayed on the prompt.
Please let me know if there is any correction that needs to be made to the above command.

Comment: Can you have spaces at the start of a line? If so, show an example of that in your posted sample input/output. It makes a difference to whether we should be testing `$1` or `$0`.

Comment: There would be no spaces at the start of a line. Also, I was able to complete the task using Håkon, William, Henk and John suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

To print the lines starting with a digit, you can try the following:

```
awk '/^[[:digit:]]+/' file
```

as pointed out by @HenkLangeveld your syntax is incorrect. Also the regex `\d` is not available in awk.

Comment: Technically the syntax was correct. ;-) The result just happens to be equivalent to  `{ 1 }` or `{ 0 }`.

Comment: @HenkLangeveld Yes the syntax was correct according to awk, but not according the human intention :)

Comment: Thanks Håkon for your inputs.

Comment: The word for what was wrong is "semantics". Syntactically the code was valid, but semantically it didn't do what was intended. No need for the `+`, just `/^[[:digit:]]/` is enough.

Comment: This didnt work. I tried doing: iostat -dx | awk ' $1 == "/^[[:ada:]]+/" { print $1 }' but it gave me nothing

Answer (score 3):

If you only need to match at least one digit at the start of the line, all you need is `^` to match the start of a line and `[0-9]` to match a digit.

You can use curly brackets with an `if` statement:

```
awk '{if($1 ~ /^[0-9]/) print $0}' filename
```

But that would just be longhand for this:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^[0-9]/' filename
```

Comment: Thanks John for your inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Drop the braces and the `\d`, like this:

```
awk ' $1 ~ /^[0-9]/ ' filename
```

Awk programs come in chunks.  A chunk is a `pattern` `block` pair, where the `block`
defaults to `{ print }`.  (An empty pattern defaults to **true**.)

The `/\d/` is a perl-ism and might work in some versions `awk` - not in those that I tried*. You need either the *traditional* `/^[0-9]/` or the *POSIX* `/^[[:digit:]]/` notation.

*
gnu and ast

Comment: Thanks Henk for your inputs

Answer (score 2):

From your attempted solution, it looks like you want:

```
 awk 'NF>1 && $1 ~ /^[0-9.]*$/' filename
```

You need to explicitly match the `.` if you want to include the decimal point, and you need the `$` anchor to make the `*` meaningful.  This will miss lines in which the first column looks like `5e39` or `-2.3`.  You can try to catch those cases with:

```
awk 'NF>1 && $1 ~ /^-?[0-9.]*(e[0-9*])?$/' filename
```

but at this point I would tell you to use `perl` and stop trying to be more robust with `awk`.
Perhaps (this will print blank lines...not sure which behavior you want):

```
perl -lane 'use POSIX qw(strtod); my ($num, $end) = strtod($F[0]);
    print unless $end;' filename
```

This uses strtod to parse the number and tells you the number of characters at the end of the string that are not part of it.

Comment: Thanks William for your inputs. Also, I can't use perl as the task in hand allows only the usage of unix commands.